# Fixed sidebar with one overflowing content and one fixed content

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position, fluid-layout

I'm working on a simple layout, but one thing is bugging me.
I want a layout with two columns, full height, a sidebar and the content.
Inside the sidebar, I want two things:

- One button that will be positioned at the bottom, fixed height.
- One div that will be centered in the remaining space, fluid height.

I try to be IE 9 compatible.

This is the basic layout:

```
<aside>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Item menu</li>
        <li>Item menu</li>
        <li>Item menu n</li>          
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <a class="btn">
    button must be at the bottom
  </a>
</aside>
<main>
  My content
</main>
```

And the basic css:

```
* { margin:0; padding: 0; box-sizing:border-box; }
html, body { height: 100%; }
aside, main { height: 100%; }
aside {
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width: 200px;
  background:#eee;
}
main {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  margin-left:200px;
}
```

For now, anything I try result in having problem when the window height is small. (The button over the menu, or no scrollbar for the menu, etc...)

What I've tryed:

- `aside{display:table}`, `.wrapper{display:tablle-cell; vertical-align:middle}` with `.btn{position: fixed; bottom:0; left:0;}`
- `nav{top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);}` but then, there is a point where the content of the nav will go on top of the viewport...
- and a bit of flexbox, but I could'nt achieve the wanted result.

If you need more information, I would be more than welcome to give them.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you get started.

**UPDATED**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

aside,
main {
  /*   height: 100%; */
  /*   width: 100%; */
}

aside {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 6;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.btn {
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #bada55;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Item menu</li>
        <li>Item menu</li>
        <li>Item menu n</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a class="btn">
button
  </a>
  </div>

</aside>
<main>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque ex, obcaecati eveniet distinctio provident tempora, voluptatum, quisquam dicta autem blanditiis quae consectetur cupiditate aliquam architecto quia, labore dolores qui unde.Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque ex, obcaecati eveniet distinctio provident tempora, voluptatum, quisquam dicta autem blanditiis quae consectetur cupiditate aliquam architecto quia, labore dolores qui unde.Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque ex, obcaecati eveniet distinctio provident tempora, voluptatum, quisquam dicta autem blanditiis quae consectetur cupiditate aliquam architecto quia, labore dolores qui unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque ex, obcaecati eveniet distinctio provident tempora, voluptatum, quisquam dicta autem blanditiis quae consectetur cupiditate aliquam architecto quia, labore dolores qui unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Doloremque ex, obcaecati eveniet distinctio provident tempora, voluptatum, quisquam dicta autem blanditiis quae consectetur cupiditate aliquam architecto quia, labore dolores qui unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Doloremque ex, obcaecati eveniet distinctio provident tempora, voluptatum, quisquam dicta autem blanditiis quae consectetur cupiditate aliquam architecto quia, labore dolores qui unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Doloremque ex, obcaecati eveniet distinctio provident tempora, voluptatum, quisquam dicta autem blanditiis quae consectetur cupiditate aliquam architecto quia, labore dolores qui unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque
    ex, obcaecati eveniet distinctio provident tempora, voluptatum, quisquam dicta autem blanditiis quae consectetur cupiditate aliquam architecto quia, labore dolores qui unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque ex, obcaecati
    eveniet distinctio provident tempora, voluptatum, quisquam dicta autem blanditiis quae consectetur cupiditate aliquam architecto quia, labore dolores qui unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque ex, obcaecati eveniet
    distinctio provident tempora, voluptatum, quisquam dicta autem blanditiis quae consectetur cupiditate aliquam architecto quia, labore dolores qui unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque ex, obcaecati eveniet distinctio
    provident tempora, voluptatum, quisquam dicta autem blanditiis quae consectetur cupiditate aliquam architecto quia, labore dolores qui unde.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Well, indeed it's a good start. 

Thank you !

Except that the `aside` is not `position: fixed;`

I've continued with your base, here is a codepen :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZVOEy

But as you will see, if the window height is small the firsts items in the `nav` are over the top of the vieport

Comment: Your post helped me a lot !

Thank you very much

Comment: Please select it  as the answer if it helped you. ☺

Comment: Well, if you want, but I had to make many changes. You didn't used `position: fixed` for the aside wich was one of the important point. ;)

Comment: Because you don't need position absolute. You can do what you need without that :) Tha's why

Comment: Not `absolute`, but `fixed`. The sidebar must always be there when you scroll. In your snippet, if I scroll down, the sidebar will move upward.

Comment: Yes you can use fixed sidebar or you can simply overflow the right side and use the current layout. I have updated the code. :)

Comment: Hello, thanks again for your time.
I worked with your updated version. It seems that I have a problem with `align-items:center`. See this pen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqxvQO , everything works fine, even with window with a small height, but if you add `display:flex; align-items:center` to `nav`, then on small window, firsts items will go on top of the viewport. It drives me crazy

Comment: I think I'll go with javascript, it'll take 5min... :)